# Delete printer HP M401A completely to upgrade

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer

In my machine there is an old version for HP M401A.
I have downloaded latest version to upgrade.
While running new driver version or even same version, there is a process for removing old version and then restart PC. After delete is completed and machine will be restarted, I run driver again to install, but same process will repeat (delete old driver and reboot PC).
It seems maybe old driver can't be deleted completely.
I have deleted installed printer from device and printers section but no chance.
I can't find printer from computer management page.
Maybe somebody can help me how to do this work successfully?
I use Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

When you are done doing what you think is an uninstall.. before doing anything else..

Open an elevated command prompt (meaning cmd.exe as admin)

Run
`pnputil /enum-drivers|more`

Look through the list for your HP drivers.  It will have a PUBLISHED NAME that looks like "oemXXX.inf" where XXX is some number.
Run
`pnputil /delete-driver <oemXXX.inf> /uninstall /force /reboot`

If it doesn't reboot.. do it yourself now and try again.

Please let me know if this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

1. From Devices & Printers, delete the printer
2. Go to Control Panel and uninstall anything to do with the printer
3. Go back to Devices & Printers, click any other driver and select Print Server Properties from the menu that appears at the top.
4. Click the Drivers tab and remove the printer from the list.