# My HP laserjet printer keeps having problems

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer, laser-printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP Laserjet P1102 printer. Recently whenever I connect it to my laptop although it gets connected, but it won't print. I came up with a solution for this which works, but it rather hides the problem than solving it. Here is what I do:

First, I go to Printers and devices and remove the printer device which is set as default (it shows two printers although I have one, one of which has a check mark by it and the other one seems kind of blurry). After removing it my computer seems to find some file which is the driver given by the factory (although I don't put the CD in), then I reinstall the software and my printer works properly for some time, but still in Devices and printers I see two printers.

I have Windows 7 SP1.

Any help is appreciated.

After @spikey_richie told me to install full-feature HP software that is how the problem looks like now: I'm still able to solve the problem by reinstalling the app again and again, but that doesn't seem to be a good way.

[enter image description here][1]

[1]:

ps: my printer is connected via USB
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWEba.jpg

Comment: Do you have the full-feature HP software installed for your device from https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-pro-p1102-printer-series/4110394? There looks to be a firmware update there as well, have you applied that?

Comment: hi, I  downloaded the software and installed it and removed last printer software I had but this time computer cant find the printer at all and it only shows the driver files given by the printer itself

Comment: How are you connected to the printer? USB, WIFI, Wired LAN ? Please add that information to your question. You can edit the question.

Comment: it's connected via USB

Comment: Unplug the printer, Remove ALL printers shown,  Uninstall the HP software, Follow the instructions I just posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1610860/delete-printer-hp-m401a-completely-to-upgrade/1611005#1611005) to completely remove the driver and reboot.  Plug the printer back in.  If it works after doing its thing, DONT INSTALL HP ANYTHING.  If it doesn't go ahead and re-install the HP software (ugh crap bloatware).  Please let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas thanks for your guide as soon as I do it I will let you know about it