# How to Reset Windows 10 to Fix Windows Print

Tags: windows-10, printing, printer, windows-10-v1909

Printing to my HP 6970 printer using the Windows 10 print UI or through the HP app has not been working for me. The printer works just fine, and I can print to it from my computer without using the Windows 10 printing UI, such as by printing in chrome (using ctrl+p or ctrl+shift+p). However, whenever I try to print to it using the print UI or the HP printer app it does not work. For example, when I try to print a PDF in Xodo I got the error code 0x800705b4. A similar issue has occurred before, and in order to fix that I copied the printconfig.dll file from spool to the 3 folder, but I tried that again this time and it says that the file is in use, so I can't copy it. I have also tried just about every other fix on the internet (spooling stuff, windows update, driver stuff, printer settings, network settings, reinstalling xodo, reinstalling hp print app, etc.) and nothing has worked.
Unless any of you somehow have outsmarted the internet and know a solution to this, I plan on reinstalling Windows 10 to fix this issue. However, I don't want to delete my files or applications, etc. Through the windows recovery settings you don't have the option to save applications too, although I know that you can using setup.exe application as is seen in method 1 here https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/refresh-windows-10-without-losing-programs-4348.html. However, I'm wondering if method 1 on that website will solve my issue, since I'm still keeping all my apps and Windows settings. Please let me know if this will work, or if there's a better alternative that does not require me to delete all of my apps to fix the printer issue, such as if there's a way to just reset or reinstall everything to do with printing on Windows 10. Also, in case it is useful to solving the problem, I'm using Windows 10 version 1909 and this issue has been occurring for at least a few weeks. Thanks.

Edit: I realized that there was another windows update that I could install and now printing works on windows version 20H2. Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: So.. I wrote win32 print drivers XP->win10.  About 200 of them.. but I am still guessing ;)  .. The error code you are dealing with has NOTHING do do with the printer sub-system and everything to do with windows update.  Perhaps windows update can't succeed because a  file from the print sub-system is locked?  .. even that doesn't make sense but it is the best that I can do.  Stop the windows spooler.  Use the method from me [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1610860/delete-printer-hp-m401a-completely-to-upgrade/1611005#1611005).. try again.. if still failed, I will give you more hints.

Answer (score 2):

You have two questions here:

**(1) HP 6970 Printer Driver:**

This driver is available for Windows 10. There is also a Firmware update that you should apply to your printer.

First, clear the Print Spooler.

> Right-click “Command Prompt” and select “Run as administrator“.
>
> *Type net stop spooler then press “Enter“. Type del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers* /Q then press “Enter“. Type net
> start spooler then press “Enter“. The print queue on your Windows
> should now be cleared.*

Now uninstall the Printer, go to Devices and Printers, Driver tab and remove the Driver. Restart the computer and install from the HP site below. Also update the Printer firmware. Test to see if the printer works.

If the printer still does not work, uninstall it again and the install the Windows 10 Printer Driver. Devices and Printers, Add Printer and add it that way.

[HP 6970 Driver for Windows 10](https://support.hp.com/my-en/drivers/selfservice/model/8289586)

> Install HP Smart and add your printer
>
> HP Smart will help you:
>
> Install printer software and drivers Connect to Wi-Fi Create an HP
> account and register your printer Load paper and install ink or toner
> cartridges

**(2) Repair Windows:**

If you truly believe a Windows repair is needed (nothing above has worked), then do a Repair Install from the Microsoft site (not a third party site). Note there are 3 possible methods below - Start with Keep Everything and try that.

Go to the Media Creation Link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Try the printer reinstall first and fall back to Windows Repair install second.

The Repair may update the version you are running at the same time.

Comment: Good answer @John but I 100% ***guarantee*** that this has nothing to do with the Printer firmware (I am an expert).  The second part of your answer is really good and the first part certainly should not hurt.  I am recommending that this is a good answer anyways.  I myself would fight my way through fixing this without a repair.. but that is me.

Comment: I understand and agree, but since Firmware was a critical update on the HP site, I thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Do NOT upgrade printer firmware to fix problems, it just invites more problems - especially in the case of HP. f/w should only be updated if a) you KNOW it fixes a problem you have or b) it installs a new feature you would like (and you believe in Santa Claus).